# PubNub android get message meta in subscribe callback

Tags: android, callback, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I'm looking at the documentation and I can't find out how to do this.

I know I can use meta from the connection object to filter results, but I want to get the meta values from inside the overriden message method in the SubscribeCallback. Can I do this?

This thing, if it makes any difference:

```
@Override
        public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message) {
            // Handle new message stored in message.message
            if (message.getChannel() != null) {
                // Message has been received on channel group stored in
                // message.getChannel()

                //If a chat message, send to chat fragment. If a task being added or deleted, update task fragment accordingly.



            } else {
                // Message has been received on channel stored in
                // message.getSubscription()

                //If a chat message, send to chat fragment. If a task being added or deleted, update task fragment accordingly.



            }
```

Comment: did you try this API `message.getUserMetadata()`

Comment: Does something need to be enabled to generate user metadata? All of the calls I make to getUserMetadata() return null objects.

Comment: @CraigConover - please see above. Thank you!

Comment: What am I looking at? There isn't really any code in the callback.

Comment: This never executes for me: if(message.getUserMetadata() != null) {
                    eimLog.logDebug("has user metadata" +message.getMessage().asText());

                }

Comment: How are you able to get metadata associated with your messages? Do we need access management enabled?

Comment: Anyone figure this one out?

Comment: This is being addressed. Feedback coming soon.

Comment: This has been addressed in the latest version - [just released today](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android/pubnub-android-sdk-v4)